# WebAPI returns "Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely."

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a relatively simple REST API implemented in a WebApi2 application with various controllers, passing JSON'd objects back and forth. It's been running pretty well, or so I thought. The http calls to the server come from an Android app using Volley.

One request was failing, apparently on the client side, so I simulated it using Intellij's HTTP Client

Here's what that request looks like (in Intellij's format). For what it's worth, I don't think this matters. I'm putting it here to show that the object isn't a monster. I'll post the Object code if anyone thinks it would help.

```
POST http://localhost:1430/api/Bids/
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"BidText":"1C","Board":2,"Counter":0,"Direction":"E","Erased":false,"Id":0,"RoundNumber":1,"SectionId":1,"TableNumber":1}
```

In doing this, I got a surprise. It looks to be some infinite loop all right, happening on the server side, but said loop does not appear to be in any of my code. In fact, I would not have known the server had received any request at all if not for my looking at it this way. It happily returned an HTTP 500 to my app without bothering to let me know (as an aside, I'd like to be at least be able to log that!)

White space added for readability:

{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",

"ExceptionMessage": "Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on the stack using too much stack space.",

"ExceptionType": "System.InsufficientExecutionStackException",

"StackTrace": "   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.EnsureSufficientExecutionStack()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, BodyModelValidatorContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, BodyModelValidatorContext validationContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, BodyModelValidatorContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, BodyModelValidatorContext validationContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, BodyModelValidatorContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, BodyModelValidatorContext validationContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, BodyModelValidatorContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)\r\n   at System.Web.H

etc, etc.

I'm not even sure where to begin looking to find why this occurs.

Here is where my routes are declared

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });


    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
```

The controller method that doesn't make it to is declared like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(Bid))]
public IHttpActionResult PostBid([FromBody] Bid bid)
{
```

It's probably worth noting that the Bid object is declared within the EntityFramework, and this is a new object that I'm trying to put into the database. This object is not be attached to the DBContext object yet.

Bid class follows. I'm wondering if I should [JSONIgnore] the associated objects (they already exist in the database, but were not transmitted over the http connection)

```
    [Table("BiddingData")]
    public class Bid : ObservableObject
    {

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("Section", Order = 1)]
        public int SectionId { get; set; }

        [Column("Table", Order = 2)]
        public int TableNumber { get; set; }

        [Column("RoundNumber", Order = 3)]
        public int RoundNumber { get; set; }

        [Column("Board", Order = 4)]
        public int Board { get; set; }

        [Column("Counter", Order = 5)]
        [Index("IX_Counter", IsUnique = false)]
        public int Counter { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 6)]
        public string Direction { get; set; }

        [Column("Bid", Order = 7)]
        public string BidText { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 8)]
        public DateTime DateLog { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 9)]
        public DateTime TimeLog { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 10)]
        public bool Erased { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public String ElapsedTime { get; set; }


        [Column(Order = 11)]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public String IpAddress { get; set; }

        public virtual Round Round { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public String BidValue
        {
            get
            {
                switch (BidText)
                {
                    case "X":
                    case "XX":
                        return BidText;
                    case "P":
                        return "PASS";
                    default:
                        switch (BidText.Substring(1))
                        {
                            case "N":
                                return BidText.Substring(0, 1) + "N";
                            case "C":
                                return BidText.Substring(0, 1) + "♣";
                            case "D":
                                return BidText.Substring(0, 1) + "♦";
                            case "H":
                                return BidText.Substring(0, 1) + "♥";
                            case "S":
                                return BidText.Substring(0, 1) + "♠";
                            default: return "";
                        }

                }
            }
        }

        [NotMapped]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Brush ForegroundColor
        {
            get
            {
                Color color;

                switch (BidText)
                {
                    case "X":
                    case "XX":
                    case "P":
                        color = Colors.White;
                        break;
                    default:
                        switch (BidText.Substring(1))
                        {
                            case "C":
                                color = Colors.DarkGreen;
                                break;
                            case "D":
                                color = Colors.Yellow;
                                break;
                            case "H":
                                color = Colors.Red;
                                break;
                            case "S":
                                color = Colors.Blue;
                                break;
                            case "N":
                            default:
                                color = Colors.Black;
                                break;
                        }

                        break;

                }

                return new SolidColorBrush(color);
            }
        }

        [NotMapped]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Brush BackgroundColor
        {
            get
            {
                switch (BidText)
                {
                    case "X":
                        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
                    case "XX":
                        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    case "P":
                        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                    default:
                        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

                }
            }
        }

        [NotMapped]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public String TableString
        {
            get
            {
                if (Round?.Section != null)
                {
                    return Round.Section.Letter.Trim() + "-" + TableNumber;
                }

                return TableNumber.ToString();                
            }

        }

        //TODO i18N
        [NotMapped]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public String BoardString
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.Round != null)
                {
                    return "Round #" + this.RoundNumber + " - Board #" + this.Board + " - " + this.Round.NSPair + " VS " + this.Round.EWPair;
                }                
                else
                {
                    return "Board #" + this.Board;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your controller action code

Comment: I've put a breakpoint at the first line of code in it, and it doesn't make it there. Would the declaration of the method be enough to help?

Comment: If you use a dumb DTO / viewmodel (not using EF) does the bug still occur?

Comment: Not using DbGeography. I'll post the Bid Class. I wish I could come up with a more minimal example. This works with certain data being posted. It doesn't with others. I'll update the question with the Bid object. I'll try it with a dumb object just to be sure, but I'm certain it won't matter because there is no Context where its failing.

Comment: `This works with certain data being posted. It doesn't with others.` please show us the data that does work, and the data that doesn't.

Comment: Good point and thank you for the sanity check. Going to start yanking the last set of changes out from this object.

Comment: Aha. I was mistaken about the old data test that was suceeded. One or more of those NotMapped/JSONIgnore field getters appears to be getting evaluated at object instantiation time (See "BidValue" and beyond). It works if I make a DTO without them and use that in the Controller and copy the fields into a "real" Bid object. I'm kind of befuddled by this. the getters check to see if the related objects exist to make sure this sort of thing won't happen.

Comment: mjwills: Since now I have a better example, I may post a better question and delete this one unless you (and SO etiquette demand that I don't). Sound good?

Comment: What is happening is that if I make field1 return the value of field2 (or even look at it), I'm getting this condition. Is there some order, or some way to specify the order the CLR does this, or is this sort of thing a a bad practice?

Comment: Comment out the extra properties, one by one. When the problem goes away, the last one you removed caused the issue. Which one caused the issue?

Comment: Also, have a think about what happens if `BidValue` is called when `BidText` is `null`.

Comment: I changed all those fields to return a constant values that didn't look at any other fields, and it STILL blew up before making it to the controller. I think it's having to do with the fact there's no setter on them. I was able to make it work using a DTO that didn't have those fields and then copying them to a Bid instance in the controller. I'm beginning to think this is some weirdness with JSON.NET trying to create such objects but I'm honestly grasping..

Comment: Say like this https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/703 (FWIW, making a private setter didn't help. Wondering if a public setter would)